# Angular2 how to delete element in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I delete an element from an `ngFor`? I have this `ngFor` of items which has an `Id` as well which I'm passing in the `updateOrder()` function so It'd know which item I'm clicking.

```
getOrdersFromOrigin() {
    this.sharedService.getOriginSite()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.orderPreparing = data.Results
      })
  }

<div class="preparing" *ngFor="let prepare of orderPreparing">
 <p> {{ prepare.Item }} </p>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateOrder(prepare.Id)">It's Ready</button>
</div>
```

In my `updateOrder` I don't have anything in my updateOrder function as I'm not sure how to delete an element relative to the `Id` I pass in the `(click)=""` event, it's giving me the `Id` just fine.

This `updateOrder()` is working as it removes it from the UI, but the idea is once its remove I want to add it to a collection.

```
updateOrder(id) {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.orderPreparing.length; i++) {
  if (this.orderPreparing[i].Id === id) {
      this.orderPreparing.splice(i, 1);
      this.addToCollection.push(this.orderPreparing[i]);
      console.log(this.addToCollection);
      console.log('Changed Status to AwaitingToPick');
      break;
  }
}
  }
```

I've added a new `private addToCollection = []` to push the removed `item` to an array so I can add it in the collection. However the code above only takes the last `index` when I add another one to the array it breaks the array becomes `[Object{}, undefined]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what tou're looking for is deleting it from orderPreparing object (if you, of course, don't have a back-end for deleting it). You can try this one:

```
updateOrder(id) {
    for(item in orderPreparing) {
        if(item[id] == id) {
            delete this.orderPreparing.item;
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a back-end app for it, you need to check if there is a script to delete the order on your back-end, made a function to call in your service which is responsible for the communication with your api, then include the service in your component, call a function to delete the order and update the orders once again.

Comment: There will be one, I've updated the original post I've added where I get the data for `ngFor`.

Comment: Well atm just to delete it from the UI, because once I click the button it will remove from the Prepare panel then move it to Pickup.

Comment: I'm sorry @MrNew, but I don't really get what you're asking right now. 
If you want to delete the item from orderPreparing, you have an answer already, but when you refresh the page, data are going to be refreshed and it will show you the item once again as it is not deleted on the back-end.

Comment: Yeah I didn't say your answer is wrong, just stating that for now its just removing from the UI :) I've already ticked your answer.

Comment: I understand. I just didn't get you at first. I've added there the "basics" of how to do that, but without any knowledge of your back-end and file structure I can't tell you exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple way to do this. Check out this, if I am not late:

```
updateOrder(id) {
  for(let i = 0; i < this.orderPreparing.length; i++) {
    if (this.orderPreparing[i].Id === id) {
        this.orderPreparing.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope will work for you.

Comment: This is a good answer, assuming we both understand what the question is asking.

Comment: Oh cool, thanks :) yeah that's what I wanted. I thought I would  need to do an `indexOf().splice()`

Comment: @AvneshShakya just to follow up, I've updated my question above. Once I remove the `id/item` I want them to be added in the collection of let say `ReadyToPick`. See the edit above or shall I create a new question?

Comment: You need to push in **orderPreparing** before removing from **orderPreparing** in if condition: 
    `this.addToCollection.push(this.orderPreparing[i]);this.orderPreparing.splice(i, 1);`  Hope will work for you. Thanks